# Retrieving from RabbitMQ after a specific time perioid

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq, jms

I am using Rabbit MQ , and want to add items to a specific queue with a paramater which contains the time in milliseconds, after which the message should be available for being consumed. 
Is this possible in Rabbit MQ. I have been trying to find out a possible way of doing this, with not much success.

Actual requirement is that though the processing of request finishes before a specific time, i have to wait before i sent the response.I have implemented this by just waiting the thread till for the required time period. But this implementation has a problem that my threads will be idle and waiting and this is also preventing from process other request.

Answer (score 0):

the Delayed Message Exchange plugin should do what you need: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange